# Xamarin Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Mupdf

Tags: android, xamarin, mupdf

I'm getting this error in my.cs:

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
>    {DesignLibrary_Tutorial.DesignLibrary_Tutorial/com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity};
>    have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

This is the my.cs code:

```
File file = (File)fileFromAsset(this, "test.pdf");
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.AbsolutePath);
var intent0 = new Intent(this, typeof(MuPDFActivity));
intent0.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
intent0.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
intent0.SetData(uri);
StartActivity(intent0);
```

And this is my android.manifest tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<activity android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-cbz" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps" />
    <data android:host="*" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
    <data android:host="*" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz" />
    <data android:host="*" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Which NuGet package are you using for MuPDF??

Comment: is solved. hehe. thanks for attention :D